# 'float' object is not callable error

Tags: python

I have a function in a class I have written that reads a reading on a magnetometer and converts it into a direction between 0 and 359 degrees. The function is as follows:

```
def heading(self):
    self.xzy = self.__GetCompassMag()
    self.x = self.xzy[0]
    self.y = self.xzy[2]
    pi = 3.14159
    self.heading = round((math.atan2(self.y, self.x) * 180) / pi)

    if self.heading < 0:
        return int(360 + self.heading)
    else:
        return int(self.heading)
```

When I try to call the function with `print obj.heading()`, the python shell gives my the error "TypeError: 'float' object is not callable". I have some experience in coding, but not much in python. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Because you override you `heading` method in a plain instance variable in this line

```
self.heading = round((math.atan2(self.y, self.x) * 180) / pi
```

Don't use `self` to write your local variable because with `self` you will be referring an instance variable, try todo this:

```
def heading(self):
    self.xzy = self.__GetCompassMag()
    self.x = self.xzy[0]
    self.y = self.xzy[2]
    pi = 3.14159
    heading = round((math.atan2(self.y, self.x) * 180) / pi)

    if heading < 0:
        return int(360 + heading)
    else:
        return int(heading)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print obj.heading()
```

needs to be:

```
print obj.heading
```

take off the bracket. anyways i saw this because i encountered the same problem while doing my own project using an object. (course im using python 3)

hope this helps!